# "He’s always playing a part." means "He always tells a lie."?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "He’s always playing a part."

One dictionary says the above sentence means figuratively that he acts in a manner making things which are not true look true.

I wonder what the sentence will mean when you hear it.

Comment: Literally it means "He's always acting the role of a character in a play/movie" *i.e.* "He's always playing someone he isn't" or "He always masks his true character." What exactly that means depends on the context... is the speaker angry, amused, resigned, joking, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of itself that absolutely wouldn’t mean he is lying. It doesn’t even necessarily mean he is masking his true character, the part he is playing could be how he sees himself, or alternatively how he thinks he should be.

It could mean that his actions and words are a bit deliberate.  Someone might say a young priest is always playing the part of “village priest”, to indicate that he uses his conception of a village priest to dictate how he should respond to situation.

Sticking to the religious theme, it’s like the question “What would Jesus do”, except applied to some role in a story.  So, it appears as if the person is constantly asking themselves “what would ??role?? do” and then takes the answer as what they should do.  This isn’t to be taken too literally, you wouldn’t expect them to actually be asking themselves the question, just that it appears that way.

The role can anything from social ditz to a dangerous criminal, from statesman to greedy business man. And playing the part can be from somewhat unconsciously to quite deliberate.

Alternative, as applied to a young child, it could simply mean he likes to play and is constantly pretending to be some character in a comic or movie.  Someone you might ask the question “Who are you today” and get an answer like “Peter Parker” or “Kermit the Frog”.

Now, it could mean he was lying, you might say that about an undercover policeman or a spy.  You could use that to describe a con-man, particularly if involved in a long con.  The shill or roper for instance, might be doing or saying something completely outside their true character, but they need to play their part or the con won’t work (not to mention the fact that it’s a con).